# Can I travel to Germany with a criminal record?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, germany, criminal-records

My husband and I are planning a trip to Germany from New Zealand. We both have a criminal history and would like to travel for snowboarding. We are unable to go to Japan, so hoping someone can offer some friendly advice for trying to travel to these places.

Comment: Criminal history in New Zealand or in Germany? If in Germany, what are the exact circumstances? What is your citizenship?

Comment: This will depend greatly on the criminal history, how much clean history you've had since, and Germany's concerns about that sort of criminal activity.  The U.S. will refuse to enter people, at times, who have nothing more than a simple impaired driving charge in their history, so it is difficult to give a certain answer.  Germany may have some process you can follow to guarantee the convictions won't prevent admission, e.g. pardoning, but there is a lot of hassle and expense and conditions involved in such efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What conditions need to be fulfilled to enter the Schengen zone visa free?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103019/what-conditions-need-to-be-fulfilled-to-enter-the-schengen-zone-visa-free)

Comment: @JimMacKenzie You are making it much more complicated than it is. A criminal record alone is not a reason to  refuse entry to the Schengen area, therefore there is also no pardon process, as in many other countries. A criminal conviction in Germany *may* have led to an expulsion and eventually an entry ban for a set amount of time. If the criminal record is in New Zealand, German authorities very likely do not know about it and noone will ask if OP is trying to enter Germany.

Comment: Thank you @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that makes things very clear. my conviction is in New Zealand. from what i have gathered is we don't need a visa to visit and they do not have a declaration of criminal history on the entry card

Comment: There is no entry card when travelling to the Schengen area. Unless you are randomly selected for a spot check, look or behave suspicious, chances are high that you are 'stamped in' by the immigration officer without any questions or the need to make any statements at all.

Comment: @StuandGinHopwood I hope I am stating the obvious, but please plan your winter vacation in Europe for your summer!

Comment: I only know US & Canada, for those they look at equivalent charges. As in what level crime would it equate to in the Destination country.

Comment: I would contact German Embassy in New Zeland and write a nice letter to them letting them know about your criminal history and ask them if it could be a problem. It's a coin toss but at least you will feel safer when travelling to Europe if they agree this is no issue. Even if there is only a few percents chance to bounce, this would make me feel much less nervous.

Comment: @Maxence No need, in fact only asking for potential trouble, as embassies have a tendency to complicate things, unlike border officers

Answer (score 5):

The Schengen Area doesn't have a policy of refusing entry to people based on criminal records, unless they believe you'll pose a security hazard.

So as long as your passport has at least 3 months left on the day of intended return, and you can justify your visit if asked, you're good to go.