# Can I travel to Malta without a visa?

Tags: refugees, malta, canadian-residents

I hold a Canadian travel document, which is issued to refugees and stateless people. I am a refugee in Canada and cannot obtain my national passport l, which is Egyptian. Can I travel to Malta without a visa? I will be visiting a Maltese cousin. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What conditions need to be fulfilled to enter the Schengen zone visa free?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103019/what-conditions-need-to-be-fulfilled-to-enter-the-schengen-zone-visa-free)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk: That doesn't seem to cover refugee travel documents.

Answer (score 18):

Whether visas are required of holders of refugee travel documents is one of the corner cases that the Schengen rules have *not* harmonized between member states.

Most but not all Schengen states are parties to the multilateral [European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031). These states grant visa-free entry to refugees settled in another party state. Malta *is* a party to the agreement, but Canada *is not*, so it doesn't apply to you.

In the absence of such an agreement applying, the default situation is that holders of refugee travel documents need visas for *everywhere*.

So you need to apply for a visa from one of the Maltese consulates general in Canada (like, by the way, all other Egyptian residents of Canada do too).